# Trying to create a composite jpa object in Spring + Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, thymeleaf

I've tried to create an object with another object inside, with a form but the Object picked from a dropdown list gets converted into a String when returned from the Thymeleaf form.
Those are the entities in my project, with an 1:n relatioship between them:

Entity User

```
//imports
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column( name ="USER_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column( name ="username")
    private String username;

    @Column( name ="password")
    private String password;

    @Column( name ="email")
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(fetch= FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Post> posts;

    //setter & getters & toString

}
```

Entity Post

```
//imports
@Entity
@Table(name="POSTS")
public class Post {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="POST_ID")
private int id;

@Column(name="tittle")
private String tittle;



@Column(name="text")
private String text;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID",referencedColumnName="USER_ID")
private User user;

//getters & setters & toString
```

To create a new Post:

```
//In Controller

@RequestMapping(value = "/posts/new")
public String newPost(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("post", new Post());
    model.addAttribute("users", userService.list());
    return "addPost";       
}
```

Which returns the template that has this form:

```
<form th:action="@{/savePost}" th:object="${post}" method="post">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" th:field="${post.id}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Titulo</td>
                <td>Texto</td>
                <td>Usuario</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="${post.tittle}"
                    th:value="${post.tittle}" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="${post.text}"
                    th:value="${post.text}" /></td>

                <td><select th:field="${post.user}">
                        <option th:each="user : ${users}" th:text="${user.username}"
                            th:value="${user.id}"></option>
                </select></td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"
                    value="GUARDAR"></td>
            </tr>

        </form>
```

The action attribute in the form calls:

```
@PostMapping("/savePost")
//@RequestMapping(value = "users/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String savePost(@ModelAttribute Post post) {

    postService.add(post);
    return "redirect:/posts";
}
```

At this point, I try to create a Post and select a User from the dropdown but when attempting to save it gives me this error:

*Field error in object 'post' on field 'user': rejected value [16]; codes [typeMismatch.post.user,typeMismatch.user,typeMismatch.com.julian.bootmvchibernate.model.User,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [post.user,user]; arguments []; default message [user]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.julian.bootmvchibernate.model.User' for property 'user'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.ManyToOne @javax.persistence.JoinColumn com.julian.bootmvchibernate.model.User] for value '16'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]*

So I tried to implement a Formatter like so:

```
public class UserFormatter implements Formatter<User> {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("userService")
public GeneralService<User> userService;

@Override
public String print(User object, Locale locale) {
    return (object != null ? object.getUsername() : "");
}

@Override
public User parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
    final Integer userId = Integer.parseInt(text);
    return userService.get(userId);
}

}
```

Registering it:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BootmvchibernateApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer{

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
      registry.addFormatter(new UserFormatter());
    }



public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BootmvchibernateApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

But when this approach is tried the next error is found, this just uppon accessing the /post/new direcction (the template addPost doesn't work):

An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/addPost2.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/addPost2.html]")
.....
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringOptionFieldTagProcessor' (template: "addPost2" - line 43, col 8)
.....
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.ManyToOne @javax.persistence.JoinColumn com.julian.bootmvchibernate.model.User] for value '2'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:47)

If any more information is needed, tell me and I post it.
EDIT: this is the repository if someone is interested.
github.com/JulianBautistaVelez/JPA_Spring_Excercise

Comment: Did you try to remove this part  <td><select th:field="${post.user}">

Comment: yes, but if I do so it saves the Post in the DataBase with null on the field user_id (if I allow null values), wich is unnaceptable since the main poin of the excersise is to have a relation between the two entities and reflect it in the database

Comment: I do not think so it is related to this problem. Can you change your join column id @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID",referencedColumnName="USER_ID") like that, please ?

Comment: Done both here and in my code

Comment: Does it give the same exception still?

Comment: Yes, it still does

Comment: Can you share your repository?

Comment: https://github.com/JulianBautistaVelez/JPA_Spring_Excercise    Yes I can, sorry for the delay and thaks for trying to help me.

Comment: Is this a private repository? I could not see

Comment: yes, it was private, sorry, just now i made it public.

Comment: Did you try with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `addPost.html` except that everything is ok now.

```
    <table>
        <form th:action="@{/posts/new/mod}" th:object="${post}"
            method="POST">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" th:field="${post.id}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Titulo</td>
                <td>Texto</td>
                <td>Usuario</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="${post.tittle}"
                    th:value="${post.tittle}" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="${post.text}"
                    th:value="${newPost.text}" /></td>

                <!-- <td><select th:field="${newPost.user}">
                        <option th:each="user : ${users}" th:text="${user.username}"
                            th:value="${user.id}"></option>
                </select></td> -->

                <td><select th:field="*{user}" class="form-control">
                    <option th:each="user: ${users}"
                        th:value="${user.id}" th:text="${user.username}"></option>
                </select></td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"
                    value="GUARDAR"></td>
            </tr>

        </form>
    </table>
```

I changed `newPost` as `post` , because you are adding in here as post model.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/posts/new")
public String newPost(Model model) {
    logger.info("-- en NEW Usuario");
    model.addAttribute("post", new Post());
    model.addAttribute("users", userService.list());
    logger.info("-- -- -- LISTA DE USUARIOS -- -- --");
    System.out.println(userService.list());
    return "addPost";       
}
```

Comment: I just tried it and I still get the "Field error in object 'post' on field 'user': rejected value [/* The ID of the user*/]......  default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.julian.bootmvchibernate.model.User' for property 'user'; " error,

Comment: Can you edit your answer with what you changed? I am doing the exactly what you follow, but it does not give me any exception. I am choosing userId from dropdown and trying to create a new post and it works @JulianBautista